# Improving balance in flexbox lines

Tags: css, flexbox

So let's say I have a flexbox where, for the sake of example, each element contains an image. The purpose of flexbox in this case is to spread them evenly.

Seems easy enough. Let's try it.

```css
#flex {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#flex>div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
#flex>div>img {vertical-align:bottom}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
</div>
```

... Oh dear. That's not very well-balanced, is it?

In my actual use case, the width is `100%` as it is part of a responsive design. The problem is that at certain widths, the items end up with just one or two too many to fit on a given line, leaving the trailing item(s) to be unreasonably wide. On smaller screens, not an issue. But if the element ends up being 1920px wide when all the others are closer to 200, well... you get the idea.

Is there any way to improve the balance in flex element wrapping, or is this the best I can hope for?

Comment: How do you want the layout to be? It is still unclear to me.

Comment: In the example above, two rows of two would be nice. In my use case, it's for categories of item in the player's inventory, of which there may be a dozen or more. The design issue I'm having is that at certain combinations of screen width and inventory categories, we end up with the last category spanning the whole width of the list, which is ugly :c

Comment: It is because of `flex: 1 1 auto` which expands upto the container width. flex-grow: 1 precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems something currently not possible but planned for Flexbox Level 2.

The [planned features list](https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css-flexbox-2) isn't much detailed but I think it would be one of those:

> - Solve the “items on the last line get way too big when you're flexing” problem. More generally, “make items have a consistent flexed
>     size, regardless of how much extra space is on each line”.
>
>   - Possible solution - calculate minimum values of 1fr and alignment free space across the entire flexbox (instead of per-line) and use
>       that.
> - Flex line balancing.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm needing, yes. At least, if I can interpret the convoluted phrasing correctly XD Thanks for the information. Guess this is something that will fix itself in a few years.

Answer (score 2):

Since you commented *In the example above, two rows of two would be nice.* You will need to specify `flex-basis: 49%` which is equivalent to `width: 49%`. 49% since it involves the white-space as well.

```css
#flex {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#flex>div {
  flex: 1 1 49%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
#flex>div>img {vertical-align:bottom}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" /></div>
</div>
```

The last element is spanning the whole width because of `flex-grow: 1`. You can remove it to provide proper balancing of wrap.

```css
#flex {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#flex>div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
#flex>div>img {
  vertical-align: bottom
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x32" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The main issue with this is how dynamic the content is. I don't know in advance the number of items, or even their relative width (the use of identical images was as an example), so I can't say "it should be two columns" at all times...

Comment: So you mean to say if there are 6 items, divide it into two rows of 3 equally. 8 items, then two rows of 4. Likely?

Comment: That's the ideal, yes. The eight items could be divided at 5-3 depending on individual widths. The point is to avoid ending up with 7-1 at certain screen sizes (which are not pre-determined since elements are dynamic)

Comment: Unfortunately, Flexbox is not a grid system. You can either use CSS columns or wait for CSS grid system: http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css-grid-1-20150917/

Also 7-1 will not occur if you avoid using `flex-grow: 1`.

Answer (score 2):

After battling with this for a while, I just went with floats instead. Flex model so far just doesn't deal with this well.

However, if you really want to, you can do some crazy selector stuff like this:

```
// in case of e.g. 7 items, 10 items, etc
.item:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child { 
  max-width: 33%;
}

// in case of e.g. 8 items, 11 items, etc
.item:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2) {
  max-width: 33%;
}
.item:nth-child(3n+2):nth-last-child {
  max-width: 33%;
}
```

(You can scale this to any number of columns. This is obviously simpler if using a CSS compiler like Sass.)

Comment: I think this was just the type of answer the OP was searching for: a sufficiently robust solution in the absence of native (flex display) support. I also found this blog post https://www.lottejackson.com/learning/quantity-queries-and-flexbox-part-2 which uses the same idea to solve a similar problem. (Why doesn't she just apply flex-grow to every item? If you read her Part 1, you'll see that she initially wanted the the first row to have the lesser number of items.) Oh, and also https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css who made nice visuals for a slightly different problem.